# heroku and vendor/plugins: does that work?

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-plugins, refinerycms

I have a RoR app 2.3.8 based on refinerycms.

I had to add search functionality.
For search, there is a gem for refinerycms, which is unfortunately for rails3.

In order to use that, I had to

git clone the plugin
git checkout the specific version

The plugin is in vendor/plugins.
then I test everything locally, the search runs fine!
If I push to heroku (git push heroku master),
the search does not work.

Everything is committed, heroku server has been restarted.
Logs show no error.

- Is there any problem if that plugin is in vendor/plugins for heroku?
- Do I somehow need to activate the plugin?
- Is the git checkout to the older version in the plugin a problem? I have a .git folder there, which version will be pushed to heroku?
- What else could be wrong?

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0):

Somehow the git process broke this. I had a .git subfolder in my plugin. I pushed to heroku and it didn't work.

So I checked out from heroku again to see what was there - the vendor/plugins folder was empty! I guess the .git subfolder was the main problem.

I started over, deleted the vendor folder and did it all again.

Now it works.